# How to deal with team lead who keeps recommending you new jobs?

Tags: ethics, manager, australia, employment-bond

**Background:**

I've just joined the firm a month ago and on my first week, I realized there's a mismatch in skills and expectations. Coming from an intensive consulting background to a more relaxed environment, I've come to the realization that this job isn't for me. However, I have no choice but to stay on for a couple of years due to an employment bond (meaning I will have to pay a fee if I quit my job). I did not share this with anyone else nor show it in my body language.

Recently, my team lead started sending me potential job opportunities in a field more related to my existing skill set. She mentioned very bluntly to me that she's also looking out and that I do not have much of a future in this place due to the enormous amount of red tapes present.

**Question:** 
How do I navigate through this mess and not get swayed by my team lead's offers?

**Update**: Thanks for all the comments and I'll edit my question. This situation is in Melbourne, Australia and not India.

Comment: What is a "bond"? I haven't heard that term before.  Is this a legal thing or a relationship thing?

Comment: Its an employment bond. So if I break it, I'll have to pay a fee. The reason there's a bond is because the company paid for my relocation.

Comment: Did your blunt team lead hire you? Can she help you cancel the bond early? Would you actually be interested in any of the jobs she found for you, if the bond did not exist?

Comment: Hi, please clarify your question: When telling you to change jobs, what did the team lead say about the bond? Does she know about it? Can she waive it? Did you try to have an honest discussion with her about this conflict? And most importantly: Please clarify your goal? Do you want to leave (and avoid the bond payment)? Do you want to stay? Do you want your lead's help to find a new job, or do you want her to shut up? Please edit!

Comment: And incidentally: Since you mention employment bonds, I suppose this is in India? Please edit to clarify - the work culture is different in different areas / countries.

Comment: "I have no choice but to stay on for a couple of years due to an employment bond" - you *do* have a choice. You can leave the job and pay the fee. It's just one more piece of information to factor into whether to accept a job offer.

Comment: What’s the problem? It sounds like he’s trying to help you.

Comment: @virolino Yep she hired me and I'm not too sure about bond cancellation. Nah, I'm not interested in any of the jobs she found for me.

Comment: @sleske I'm intending to stay in the job for a while first before making a decision. Like some of the commenters mentioned below, I think I do owe the company some form of loyalty as they have hired me when I was overseas. Just found all these job offers from the team lead kind of irritating.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have no idea man

Answer (score 28):

> How to deal with team lead who keeps recommending you new jobs?

Ignore the recommendations. Focus on getting an excellent referral after your two years. Don't get roped into anyone elses career moves. You owe this company some loyalty, they haven't done anything I can see that warrants you leaving them after the investment and trust they have placed in you.

If your team lead leaves, there is an opportunity right there to step up.

Comment: +1 for the opportunity to step up if the TL leaves - I'd take that info and make sure I was trying to put myself in a position where I'd be a suitable candidate to replace her if she moved on in a few months.

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but the OP seems to feel this place is not right for him. I doubt he'd be interested in stepping up or progressing on the career ladder within the same company.

Comment: @Charmander I don't see that, OP said they don't have a choice but to remain, that doesn't mean lay down and die... to me it means look for opportunities to advance with what you're stuck with.

Comment: @Kilisi, it's a fair point. I have a different opinion and I'm waiting for more info from the OP to post my own answer. But I think OP should use the fact his TL "agrees" with him to negotiate a way out that works for both sides (i.e. finding a new job and not having to pay the bond). But I see your point.

Comment: @berry120 yep information is valuable, doesn't mean you have to use it how the informer intends, there's usually several ways of looking at it. And one should never take it at face value without thinking through the possibilities and implications in terms of personal advancement. Especially someone you barely know with one foot out the door trying to get you to leave as well.

Comment: Whilst I agree with most of your point saying "you owe this company some loyalty" is ridiculous. Loyalty has to be earned and forcing someone to stay in their job for 2 years or pay a fine really isn't conducive to earning loyalty. You have to remember, if you get hit by a bus a company will have you replaced before your body is even cold

Comment: @Persistence It's not a fine. The OP explained in the comments on the question that the bond is there because the company paid for them to relocate in order to take the job.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I missed that, even then, I'd stand by my point. Unless the company is exceptionally small, the cost to them is negligible, especially when compared to the personal risk taken by the OP in relocating.

Comment: I disagree strongly about owing the company anything, especially loyalty. You work, they pay.  That said, this is the right answer. Don't get moved by team lead attempts to get rid of you. I fell for that one, once, and I still regret it.

Comment: @Jeffrey if you buy me lunch in good faith (please do, I'm hungry, I like steak) then regardless of whether the cost was negligible to you or not I'm not going to make you regret doing so. I don't owe you much loyalty, I wouldn't take a bullet for you, but I owe you enough that if someone bad mouthed you, I'd tell them to pee off and whine to someone else.

Answer (score 4):

> I've just joined the firm a month ago and... I realized there's a mismatch in skills and expectations... I've come to the realization that this job isn't for me.

It's been a month. Don't draw this conclusion based on your gut feel just yet!

New jobs/environments often feel uncomfortable - you should even expect it. Push through this, and in a couple more months re-evaluate and see if you feel the same. You'll be under less pressure, more familiar with the job and the team, and presumably a bit more settled too if you've relocated.

> My team lead started sending me potential job opportunities... She mentioned very bluntly to me that she's also looking out and that I do not have much of a future in this place

Just a thought on this in case it didn't occur - be careful not to conflate this 'advice' with what you are feeling about the job being a bad fit.

She's leaving, clearly is critical of the organisation, and may just be encouraging *anyone and everyone* else she can to also leave. It's likely not that she thinks you're a bad fit and is suggesting this for you specifically. Or to the extent it's related, it may be just that she's read you're having an uncertain start and thinks you might be more likely to listen as a result.

The good thing is she was very direct, so you can just match that tone and be very direct back: "Appreciate you thinking of me, but I'm not interested at all in other opportunities. I want to make a go of this one here."